# JAVA Using a variable value as an Instance name

Tags: java

So basically Im reading a file , each line of this file contains description for from 3 to 5
instances of two types of objects with 2 to 4 being first type of object and last one being another type . The file can contain up to 500 lines . I am going to reuse each object from 1 
to unknown but on scale of hundrets of times and I need to track their status .

While I can all the data into an array and use only 5 objects changing their values constantly
that will make it rather hard to track status of each combination of their parameters .

What I want to is to create my instances with names such as FromLine1Obj1 , FromLine10Obj3 .

I failed to mention the fact that each set of objects from a single line should also create a new thread and this set is proccesed in that thread .

Comment: Which way classes with names should be created?

Comment: something like  Contract Line(linenumber)Obj1 = new Contract();

Comment: and then Line(linenumber).type = "Sell"

Comment: where linenumber is the number of line from which object description was taken

Answer (score 4):

You need to use a Map.

```
Map<String, MyObject> map = new ....

map.put("FromLine1Obj1", new MyObject());

MyObject mo = map.get("FromLine1Obj1");
```

Comment: Thank you for the best answer about Map , but it seems to be just a set of special arrays with additional functions .

Comment: HashMap does use an array but TreeMap doesn't. What is your doubt?

Comment: I need each line analyzed in a paralell thread . And the number of threads is based on amount of lines in my file .

Answer (score 1):

If you read the file once and it will not change after all - you may want to do some code generation, like http://cglib.sourceforge.net/

Comment: The file is basicly a list of insturctions loaded at program start up .

Comment: Does it change from compilation to compilation?

Comment: Yes the file changes from compilation to compilation , it is also changeable after compilation.

Comment: then you will need to use Map, as described in another comments.

Answer (score 0):

Could you not use a map with the name as the key?

Answer (score 0):

You can store your parsing result in a map, with as key the name you want and as value the created instance, that's the clean way around name indirection in Java.